# Delete value from array within FindOneAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

i am willing to implement action inside title with mongoose

for example document field (Array) looks like this

```
likers: ['Jakob', 'Ritchie','John', 'Tommy']
```

i want to remove 'liker' from array found with this arguments

```
let document = await Model.findOne({id: req.params.id, name: req.params.name})

let unlike = await Model.findOneAndUpdate({id: req.params.id, name:  req.params.name},
/* do something like this document.likers.splice() or something  */)
```

how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you have defined you schema properly you can do this via `update` and `$pull` like this:

```
YouModel.updateOne(
   { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) }, 
   { $pull: { 'likers': req.params.name } }
)
```

With pure mongo it is practically the same:

```
db.getCollection('YourColletion').updateOne(
  { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) }, 
  { $pull: { 'likers': req.params.name } }
)
```

Comment: I did not know about pull operator, why I can not use `$pull` inside `findOneAndUpdate`? or if I can isn't `findOneAndUpdate` better method than `updateOne`?

Comment: does it return document?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/index.html docs - updateOne docs - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/index.html. Both return document.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
    let filters = { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id), name:  req.params.name };
    let changes = { $pull: { likers: req.params.name } }; // JIC FYI, I recently learned you can add other changes here too, eg `{ timestamp: timestamo, $pull: { likers: req.params.name } }` to update timestamp as well as removing the like
    let options = { returnNewDocument: true, returnOriginal: false, new: true, upsert: true }; // the only important ones here are the `upsert` and `new`
    const findUpdate = await Model.findOneAndUpdate(filters, changes, options)
```